# Stuck compiling open source project that uses Qt. qmake never ends. Is it possible to download compiled files?

Tags: windows, qt, compilation

I am triying to compile on Windows this project: https://github.com/scantailor/

There is a detailed guide (https://github.com/scantailor/scantailor/blob/master/packaging/windows/readme.en.txt) but one process takes too time to finish. I am on point 7 (building scantailor dependencies).

The command is this:

```
C:\...\Qt\4.8.6\bin\qmake C:/.../Qt/4.8.6/\projects.pro  -o Makefile -spec win32-msvc2008
```

I think that this creates the compiled libraries of Qt, but the problem is that this command took more than 6 hour without finish.

Is another way to obtain the compiled files?

I am using Windows 8.1 and Qt 4.8.6

**UPDATE:**

Stuck here (msv2008):

```
4>For tools\xmlpatternsvalidator\xmlpatternsvalidator.pro
4>For translations\translations.pro
4>Qt is now configured for building. Just run nmake.
4>To reconfigure, run nmake confclean and configure.
4>Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 9.00.30729.01
4>Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
4> C:\legacy_programs\Qt\4.8.6\bin\qmake C:/legacy_programs/Qt/4.8.6/\projects.pro  -o Makefile -spec win32-msvc2008
2>order.c
2>Generating Code...
```

Comment: Compiling Qt takes a lot of time. Just wait. Also you can get some binaries here: http://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/4.8/

Comment: @Evgeny I installed the qt from there. The point is that scantailor needs to build depedencies and put them into subfolder. To QT there a subfolder called "Qt.dir" where is generated the compilation. From which folder can I take the compiled QT libraries to put them in that folder?

Comment: It's something like `c:\Qt\4.8.6\bin\`

Comment: The issue is that the other "foo.dir" contains file like this *.obj. I think that I am going to the official forum.

Comment: Then you shoul wait untile your compiling process finished. I'm not sure you can get `obj` files anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can't believe it. The problem was the Avast antivirus. This av blocks VS2008C++ and other related stuff. Hope this help. When I deactivated the AV the qmake started to rocks.